# Нужен простой Regex паттерн

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня не выходит составить простой Regex паттерн, который будет заменять любые слова в квадратных скобках на string.Empty . Если это имеет значение - я пытаюсь избавиться от префиксов в нике игрока, т.к. они бывают довольно длинными и это имеет определенное неудобство.

Обратите внимание, что ник игрока может содержать несколько тегов, например: `[Admin][Survivor][Faction] nickname`. Так же стоит учитывать, что после префикса/-ов ставится пробел (между префиксами и никам).

Желательный результат:

`[Admin] Фёдор` -> `Фёдор`

`[Admin][Survivor] Генадий` -> `Генадий`

Заранее благодарю!!!

Comment: Это можно сделать и без Regex, или вам необходимо именно с помощью регулярок?

Comment: ну `[[][^]]*[]]`...

Comment: `[^] ]+$` забрать последнее слово в строке

Answer (score 1):

Используя ресурс [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) можно нехитрым образом составить необходимую регулярку. `(\[.*\])` будет выделять все символы внутри квадратных скобок. Если не использовать flag `U` (ungreedy), то в таком случае все, находящеся между квадратных скобок будет потеряно.

Например: Пусть входная строка будет `[Admin] test [Survivor] test [Faction] nickname`
Без использования флага `U` в вычетающем режиме мы получим строку  `nickname`

Если использовать флаги `U` и `g` (global - regex не остановится после первого совпадения), то в таком случае результатом работы паттерна будет  `test  test  nickname`

На самом деле это довльно тривиальная задача и на будущее я советую Вам больше обрщаться к приведенному мною ресурсу и к документации которая без проблем может быть загуглена.

Спасибо

[image: Изображение с сайта]

Comment: *`(\[.*\])` будет выделять все символы внутри квадратных скобок.* Если между "оквадраченными именами"  есть что-то - оно потеряется. Обязателен флаг `Ug`.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, уточнил ответ!